# How to embed multi-line shell command in psql file

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a .sql file with some lines which look like this:

```
\set buf `cat example-message.msg | base4 -w0`
SELECT * FROM run_select(:'buf');
```

However, this hides the content of `example-message.msg` and makes my file (which is actually a list of test cases) less readable than I would like. Ideally, I'd be able to in-line the contents of `example-message.msg`. But it's a large, multi-line file.

I've tried using here-docs:

```
\set buf `cat <<EOF | base64 -w0
plan { }
EOF
`
```

However, here psql complains about an unterminated quoted string and in retrospect [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html) say it won't work anyway. (`But in any case, the arguments of a meta-command cannot continue beyond the end of the line.`)

Next I considered somehow building the string which is executed:

```
SELECT $$
plan: {}
$$ AS rawbuf \gset
\set buf `echo :rawbuf | base64 -w0`
```

This doesn't work either, for obvious reasons. But I can't seem to get any variation of it to work either. I suppose psql [doesn't do variable substitution](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/bin/psql/psqlscanslash.l#L351) within backticks.

Is there some other method I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

Multi-line meta-commands are not supported indeed. In your case, it seems like it's the round-trip to `base64 -w0` that calls for a meta-command. But it looks like you could avoid that by doing the `base64` encoding in SQL:

```
SELECT encode(convert_to($delim$
  --multi-line string
$delim$
, 'UTF-8'), 'base64') AS buf \gset

SELECT * FROM run_select(:'buf');
```

The temporary `:buf` could also be avoided if it doesn't have any other use than being reinjected:

```
SELECT * FROM run_select(encode(convert_to($delim$
  --multi-line string
$delim$
  , 'UTF-8'), 'base64')
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! While you've solved the question as posed, the actual command I'm running has a longer pipeline than just base64. I think you're right that this is the only answer though, I ended up writing a C function which shells out and lets me embed $$-deliminated strings as you've suggested.